# Lighttpd SSL Error

Tags: ssl, lighttpd

iam trying to setup SSL for my lighttpd server.
lighttpd -v shows : lighttpd/1.4.26 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver

1. I create server.pem file.
2. I add following lines into lighttpd.conf
   $SERVER["socket"] == ":443"{
   ssl.engine = "enable" 
   ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/certs/server.pem"
   }
3. I restart server, everything is OK.
4. I run: openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 and get response :
   CONNECTED(00000003)...... no errors, nothing
5. But when i want to access mydomain.com:443 via browser it fails and in error.log i can see this:

   (connections.c.294) SSL: 1 error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request

Can anyone help with this issue because i really dont know where can be problem and iam not so much linux guy, i just need to setup ssl on web server.
Thank you

Comment: I made the same mistake. I thought https and :443 were synonymous with lighttpd. I guess I was wrong. Linux/lighttpd noob here :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that you open https://mydomain.com/ and not http://mydomain.com:443/. If you use the right protocol (https instead of http) you don't need to address the port, except you use a non standard port (http=80; https=443).